Dihydrogenphosphate and hydrogenphosphate buffer solution
I have just come across a problem involving a buffer solution comprising of dihydrogenphosphate ions and hydrogen phosphate ions, which asks how the mixture of these two ions can function as a buffer solution.
From my understanding there are only two types of buffers, either a weak acid and conjugate base or a weak base and conjugate acid.
Hence, to me this buffer doesn't satisfy either of the criteria as both species are only weak. Conjugate base of a weak acid must be strong, and the conjugate acid of a weak base must also be strong. Hence this doesn't satisfy either.
I can't seem to find this buffer online, and I can't even find the chemists name for this solution. How can these two species mixed together behave as a buffer at all?
Edit: If this behaves as a buffer, what species is function as the weak acid or base and the conjugate acid or base?

One famous phosphate buffer is PBS, phosphate-buffered saline. It is easily found in an online search, pointing at lots of resources (some good).

Conjugate acids/bases to weak bases/acids are not strong, unless the bases/acids are EXTREMELY weak, like  $\ce{Cl-}$ as a base or  n-hexane as an acid.

Here dihydrogenphosphate is the acid and monohydrogenphosphate is the base. The corresponding equation is :

@Poutnik Does this mean what I have been taught is a simplification and that the two species don't have to be of opposite strengths?

The strength of the acid and it's conjugate base, expressed by their acidity and basicity constant, is related by the equation Ka . Kb = Kw=10^-14 at 25 Deg C. If Ka=10^-7 (weak acid) then its conjugate base has Kb = 10^-14/10^-7 = 10^-7, i.e. equally weak base.

Here dihydrogenphosphate ion $\ce{H2PO4^-}$ is the acid and monohydrogenphosphate ion $\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$is the base. Both ions are not strong. The corresponding donation of proton equation is : $$\ce{H2PO4^- -> H+ + HPO4^{2-}}$$ Of course it can be reversed.
